# Redirect SMS broadcast to stock SMS app

Tags: android, sms, android-4.4-kitkat

I'm building a spam-blocker app for android as a personal exercise.

For pre-KitKat versions, i used the broadcast receiver android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED without any problem. But for Kit Kat, my app needs to be the default SMS app to receive the broadcast android.provider.Telephony.SMS_DELIVER, so if a SMS is not a spam, it won't be delivered to the user.

Is there anyway to bypass this restriction ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a word, no. It should also be mentioned that, as of KitKat, the `SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION` cannot be aborted anyway.

> Note that—beginning with Android 4.4—any attempt by your app to abort the SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION broadcast will be ignored so all apps interested have the chance to receive it.

[Source](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html?m=1)

Comment: That's what i thought, i guess i'll just display an error message for > KitKat users... that's too bad! Thanks anyway.

Comment: Yep. I'm not certain if this, but I think the stock SMS app has spam filtering capability built in.

Comment: Yep, it has, but as i said it's a practice app, not meant to be published :)